# How to configure Global build discarder in jenkins using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees

I am trying to configure global build discard option in Cloudbees jenkins using groovy, For now, iam manually configuring global build discard in configure system..
But i couldnt find enough documents with the groovy.I could see scripts only for fetching the list of jenkins jobs and adding build discard property in the pipeline.

Cloudbees recommends this to run build discarder,

```
ExtensionList.lookupSingelton(BackgroundGlobalBuildDiscarder.class)doRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins configuration as code can manage the global build discarder configuration.  I use the following entry in my configuration as code:

```
unclassified:
  buildDiscarders:
    configuredBuildDiscarders:
      - "jobBuildDiscarder"
```

That's not using system groovy, but it will configure the global build discarder.  That configuration is also displayed by the configuration as code "View configuration" button.

Configuration as code is usually easier than system groovy scripts because the "View configuration" button displays the configuration currently being used.